# How do I setup PACT with my .NET microservice

Tags: c#, .net, pact, pact-net

I want to setup Pact for my .NET service.

How can I set up PACT with the microservice?

Should I make provider tests, and how would I do this since I do not have consumer tests and therefore a contract file, at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on our [slack workspace](http://slack.pact.io), I think if you’re new to Pact, you’re best creating a dummy contract to verify, publishing it to PactFlow, and then going through the process to verify it. Then when a real consumer comes along, 99% of the work is done.